# Declaring dependency on Mockito using Maven/pom.xml in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, mockito, pom.xml

I am relatively new to using Java and would like to improve these unit tests I have written by using mocks. I have heard mockito is a good library so I am trying to declare the dependency in the pom.xml file of my project but wherever I place the lines in the file, I am given an error 'Invalid content was found starting with the element 'dependency'. I have looked on the Mockito docs but they seem to jump straight in to importing at the top of your test files not actually configuring it.

My pom.xml file currently:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>JAirport</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.10</source>
                <target>1.10</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</project>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to wrap your `<dependency>` tag in a `<dependencies>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your `<dependency>` tag in a `<dependencies>` tag

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>JAirport</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.10</source>
                <target>1.10</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```